# Fill in a form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, fill

I am trying to use jQuery to fill in a form with some default values.

The form is contained in a div which has an id. In fact every element has an id, I did so just to be able to quickly select every piece of the form using `$("#id")` syntax.
Here is the form:

```
<div id="panel" style="position: absolute; left: 190px; top: 300px; width: 400px; height: 300px; border: medium groove brown; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black; z-index: 100; color: white;">
<form id="form_coord_0">  
X <input type="text" style="height: 25px; font-size: 10px;" size="2" name="X" id="coordX_0"/>  
Y <input type="text" style="height: 25px; font-size: 10px;" size="2" name="Y" id="coordY_0"/>  
<input type="button" id="edit_0" value="M"/>  
<input type="button" id="remove_0" value="-"/>  
<input type="button" id="add_0" value="+"/>  
<input type="button" id="go_0" value="go!"/>  
</form>
</div>
```

I need to set the `coordX_0` text field with some value, let's say: `123`.

I thought I could do

```
$("#coordX_0").text.value = 123;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  Any hint?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val, documentation is your friend.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, I'm quite a novice with jQuery (well, even with js:D ) I didn't even know the val() method existed.

Comment: @nick2k3 The first thing I did when learning jQuery was to go through the API documentation and see all the functions available and the demos of how to use them. I did that so I could have at least a basic idea of what the framework will allow me to do. For instance the `.val()` function can take a function as an argument if you want to handle multiple form inputs at once, you can see my answer below for an example of how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914161/fill-in-a-form-with-jquery/8914281#8914281

Comment: @Jasper my confusion was because when I googled how to edit a form with javascript I always found something like document.form[0].text.value= "123". While with jquery I have to look for some function that does that.. I only have to practice:)

Comment: @nick2k3 That will select the input named `text` in the first form in the DOM (notice the zero index means first) and set it's value to `123`. In your case you would use `document.forms[0]['coordX_0'].value = "123";` Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/86UdQ/. I still recommend reading the docs thouroughly, there **will** be some things in there you didn't know existed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to set input values

```
$("#coordX_0").val(123);
```

Incidentally, your original code could be made to work by setting value property on the actual, underlying dom element.  You access the dom element by indexing your jQuery results:

```
$("#coordX_0")[0].value = 123;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it. Do you or anyone happen to know where I can find an extensive documentation on what method I can call on such objects? (something like the JavaDoc but for javascript and DOM).

Comment: Well the jQuery docs are fantastic - but native dom docs?? - not off the top of my head.

Comment: @nick2k3 Try the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement. Just search Google (or whatever) for `[the property I want to know about] MDN` where `[the property I want to know about]` would be something like, `element value`.

Answer (score 19):

All the answers are the exact same so I thought I'd post something different:

```
var inputs_to_values = {
    'coordX_0' : 'some value',
    'coordY_0' : 'some other value',
    'edit_0'   : 'N',
    'remove_0' : '_',
    'add_0'    : '-',
    'go_0'     : 'stop?'
};
$('#form_coord_0').find('input').val(function (index, value) {
    return inputs_to_values[this.id];
});
```

You can pass `.val()` a function, whatever is returned from the function for each element will be the new value:

> A function returning the value to set.
>
> **this** is the current element.
>
> Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old
>   value as arguments.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/val*

The above code expects that each input will have a property in the `inputs_to_values` object so you can convert the ID of the input to the new value for that input.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zYfpE/

Comment: I was searching something like that, i was sure there was a native method in jquery, but this anyway is enough compact. Really like it.

Comment: This short and easy to extend method is just what I needed and think it answers the question perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To set the value of an input field its

```
$("#coordX_0").val(123)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#coordX_0").val("123");
```

You need the quotes too I think. Although it might work both ways.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead, using the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$("#coordX_0").val('some string or number');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write:

```
$("#coordX_0").val(123);
```

In `jQuery`, `text` is a function to extract text in dom.

Answer (score 2):

Use `val` method to set the text of any `input` field.

```
$("#coordX_0").val(123);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the val function

```
$("#coordX_0").val("123");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
$("#coordX_0").val("123");
```